# When a program opens a script that is referenced by a symbolic link and symbolic link changes - does it continue to point to the original file?

Tags: linux, bash, script, symbolic-link, deployment

So say I have a long running program that is run using the symbolic link below.

latest_version_of_script -> /path/to/script/v1

My program is still running and I do a release and my deployment script will update the symlink to be:

latest_version_of_script -> /path/to/script/v2

Will my long running program still continue to load the script (if it has not loaded all of it yet into memory) from the first symbolic link location or the second?

Answer (score 2):

The program will keep reading from the same file until the end.

When a program needs to read from a file, it only uses the path once – when calling the open() function. Once the file has been opened, all reads and writes are done using its "handle" or "file descriptor" which completely bypasses the name/path system and always refers to that specific item no matter its current location.

Symlinks do not change this, as they are processed during path lookup and the program always ends up opening the real target file, not the symlink itself.

But if the program closes the file and wants to reopen it later, *then* the path will be processed again, the symlink will be resolved to the new location, and the program will get the updated version.

Comment: Ok so if you imagine my program is a Cron job or Autosys that is executing a long running script the only time I would get the "v2" script is when I bounce my Autosys job and it then does the path lookup again?

Comment: That's true for cron, but I don't know how Autosys works.